# window.opener is null - I'm trying to alert a variable (from the parent window) in my child window - Javascript

Tags: javascript, parent, window.opener

I'm trying to alert a variable (from the parent window) in the child window. I've looked at solutions on here but they don't work for me and I assume there's something missing or wrong in my code. When I run the code, the error console tells me that the window.opener is null. I've tried parent.window.opener... and that also says the same thing.

parent.htm:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
            var testtest = "hi";

            function reply_click(clicked_id){

                document.getElementById('resultspanel').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('mainpanel').style.display = 'none';            

                var buttonid = clicked_id;
                window.buttonid = buttonid; //makes it global
                alert(buttonid);

                switch(clicked_id) {
                    case "1":
                    case "2":
                    case "3":
                    case "4":
                    case "5":
                    case "6":
                    case "7":
                    case "8":                   
                    case "9":
                    case "10": $('#mainpanel').load("info.htm");document.getElementById('mainpanel').style.display = 'block'; break;    
                }

                    //$('#mydiv').load('newPage.html', {field1: 'value1', ...});
            }


            </script>
</head>
```

child.htm

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
            function test(){
                //alert(this.parentNode.id);
                //alert(parent.window.opener.testtest);
                //window.opener.alert(testtest);
                var myvar = window.opener.buttonid;
                alert(myvar);
            }
        </script>
</head>
    <body>      
    <p>INFORMATION</p>
        <div id = "test" style = "border-style:solid; height:10%; width:10%;" onClick = "test();" >DIV</div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Are they nested frames? The answer is really in your question. You're trying to alert a variable from **parent** window, not from the window you opened. `window.parent.buttonid` should work

Comment: OMG You are my saviour!!!!!!! Thank you. I've been stuck on this hours!

Comment: Then you can accept my answer (below), if it adds some more value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were correct to some extent. `window.opener` is a reference to the window, which opened current one. But this is applied only for windows called with `window.open` function. And they're usually appear in new window (or tab).

If one needs to address different frames, then he should use `parent` property for direct ancestor, `top` for the topmost frame and `frames` property for direct children. There're additional complications, when you use `frameset` instead of `iframe`s (like window with frameset don't have direct content). I hope you won't need them.